# /var directory is full because mysql?

Tags: mysql, centos, space, var

My server storage is almost full. If I run a `df -h` command on Centos, it shows me that my `/var` directory is at the edge of my disk capacity like this:

```
S.ficheros          TamaÃ±o Usado  Disp Uso% Montado en
/dev/sda3             205G   23G  172G  12% /
/dev/sda2             243G  225G  5,0G  98% /var
/dev/sda1             289M   23M  251M   9% /boot
tmpfs                 1,8G     0  1,8G   0% /dev/shm
none                  1,8G  104K  1,8G   1% /var/lib/xenstored
```

If I check the total size of my files in `/var` using `du -chs` it shows:

```
5,3G    .
5,3G    total
```

I suppose that MySQL is using the 220G left, so I execute the next query to check the total size of my databases:

```
SELECT SUM((data_length+index_length)/POWER(1024,3)) tablesize_gb FROM information_schema.tables
```

and the output is the next:

```
+-------------------+
| tablesize_gb      |
+-------------------+
| 0.748469822108746 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)
```

I don't really know what am I missing here — can any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with `du -s /var/* | sort -n` and see which folder has the most stuff in it.  Then work down the file system from there.  The chances are that there's one set of log files that have grown out of control.  When you find the files, you'll have to decide what to do with them.  Delete and compress are two options — generally, delete is more effective and the chances are you won't need the files.  You may need root privileges to see inside some of the directories.

Answer (score 0):

There are other packages besides mysql that use /var and there are two possible scenarios which can cause too little space on the /var directory:

1. A couple of large files taking up a significant percentage of /var space
2. Numerous small files which collectively take up a significant percent of /var space

There are a couple like of nice suggestions listed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/9847/linux-utility-for-finding-the-largest-files-directories) such as the interactive disk usage analyzer ncdu. You can download ncdu from the epel repository.